# Why is my PHP prepared statement for MySQL not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently learning PHP and MySQL. I'm just wrote a class that handles all the MySQL traffic, but I'm encountering some errors.

```
function table_exists($tablename){
    // check if table exists
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE '?'");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $tablename); //This is line 24.
    $stmt->execute();
    $ar = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    if ($ar > 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the code with the problem, and the error i'm getting is

> Generates Warning:
>   mysqli_stmt::bind_param()
>   [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of
>   variables doesn't match number of
>   parameters in prepared statement in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mail\datahandler.php
>   on line 24

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use quotes when working with prepared statements.

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SHOW TABLES LIKE ?");
```

Also, instead of `SHOW TABLES`, you might want to use information_schema views, which give you a bit more flexibility.

Comment: Does that mean if i do this, i won't need the quote either?
$query = "DELETE FROM maillist WHERE id='?' AND" .
                     "password='PASSWORD(?)'";

Comment: After using your code, i'm getting You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Comment: Maybe SHOW TABLES does not support prepared statements in LIKE clause... Try `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND TABLE_NAME = ?` where `TABLE_SCHEMA` is name of your database, and `TABLE_NAME` is name of your table.

Answer (score 2):

You also have to use a number as first parameter for bind_param()

```
$stmt->bind_param(1, $tablename);
```

See here: http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.bindparam.php

For strings you can also just pass an array into execute().

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize you're using MySQLi, i assumed you were using PDO - which I highly recommend btw.

Answer (score 0):

```
private function table_exists($tablename){
        // check if table exists
        $stmt = $this->db->query("SHOW TABLES");
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $arr[]=$row;
        }
        $ar=0;
        foreach($arr as $val){
            foreach($val as $value){
                if($value==$tablename) $ar=1;
            }
        }
        unset($stmt);
        if ($ar == 1){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```